# Why do Stack Overflow moderators delete answers with no feasible reasons?

Tags: discussion

As much as anybody who belongs to this great community, I'm struggling to build a reputation and that invokes a great feeling in me. Recently, I answered a question but in a different context. I posted my working solution and I got upvotes for my answer (that means, similar people came across the answer and it worked for them). Then one of the moderators deleted my answer.

Why and how is this platform managed? Is it fair?

Comment: Without context, this is impossible to answer. Please read [the faq post on this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: Getting upvotes doesn't confer immunity to deletion. An answer can still be copy-pasted without attribution, or a link-only answer, or it might even not be an answer at all ("I have the same problem but with version Y, any solution"), all of which can gather legitimate but inconsequential upvotes. The FAQ also answers the question of [how moderation works](https://stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators). Spoilers: moderators are picked by "this great community" too.

Comment: *Is it fair?* --> yes it is, deletion is a feature and a privilege that anyone can use (not only moderators) in order to clean stuff and keep this community great.

Comment: this is the question, please explain prctically https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48140567/visual-studio-2017-how-to-enable-disable-servicehub-exe-components/62944316?noredirect=1#comment129950415_62944316

Comment: I think the comments on that answer pretty much explain why it was deleted.

Comment: no it isn't, because I still see it is not fair

Comment: Your comment on the question includes a common misconception: "adding value" (i.e. "someone must have read this and found it useful") is not sufficient reason to justify the existence of an answer. It should also answer the actual question, not just be something potentially useful that someone could have stumbled on through a search. Whether this is "fair" doesn't really matter: those are the rules by which the site operates. It's "fair" in the sense that these rules are out in public, available for all to read and something you implicitly agree with if you decide to post here.

Comment: Your answer didn't answer the question; it does not seem to be related to the question at all. Hence it was deleted. If you don't want answers deleted, then make sure you actually address the problem of a question.

Comment: *I still see it is not fair* --> are you ready to accept that the community doesn't agree with your opinion? what you see as a valid answer looks like a comment to me

Comment: check the link and tell my why this answer was deleted? that it

Comment: all the comments above are telling you why the answer is deleted.

Comment: Do not be 100% sure the decision was right, you have to check.  This is the first question I posted because I'm upset.

Comment: We have checked. The question was "how to disable these so that they do not start in the first place" - you did not answer that.

Comment: *because I'm upset.* --> don't be upset, we are not judging you. We are judging your "low quality" answer. Why you don't take a lesson for this to better understand how to give good answers? You will win nothing if you keep claiming you are right and everyone else is wrong.

Comment: *"As anybody who belongs to this great community struggling to build a reputation that invokes a great feeling in me."* I cannot understand what this sentence means.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "legitimate" upvotes.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: I mean upvotes from people who thought they had a good reason to upvote (regardless of whether we would agree with those reasons); perhaps "justifiable" is better. Illegitimate upvotes would include things like votes handed out by sockpuppets and voting rings.

Comment: MetaSO votes don't convey reputation so there's no real concept of a voting ring. On Meta people vote up if they agree with the the post and down if they don't. The only thing you can infer from the voting on this question is that a number of people disagree with you that it is unfair to lose reputation because an off-topic answer is deleted, and they agree with the answer below that this is perfectly normal for SO.

Comment: @MahmoudNasr - What are you talking about? Your answer didn’t answer the question you linked to, you can disagree with that viewpoint, but doesn’t change anyones else’s viewpoint. Keep in mind mine is based on 23 years working with Visual Studio

Comment: I appreciate your experience @SecurityHound, The Whole subject, I was trying to add new features using vs installer tool, after downloading the required features and starting to install, The same error message appeared to me, and I get to the question from google search, all I did, I tried to utilize from the existed answers and they were not possible to be applied on my situation, I clicked end task button that appeared on the installer and Installation process went fine, then I added my solution which faced similar people and resolved their problem.

Comment: @MahmoudNasr - Sounds like you had a different problem. You could address the concerns of the community and edit the answer.

Answer (score 20):

Your [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62944316/1038015) entered the low quality queue. The post did receive a downvote but actually entered the queue as a result of being flagged *(as confirmed by a moderator in a comment below)*. The [FAQ provides this information](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161390/what-are-the-review-queues-and-how-do-they-work) about how posts enter that queue...

> The Low quality posts queue contains both questions and answers which were automatically determined to be of low quality based on several system criteria that generates a post quality score, or which have been [flagged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) by users for being extremely low quality or, in the case of answers, not being [proper answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers).

Moderators can and do act on low quality flagged posts too and a moderator agreed with the flag and with another non-moderator who had already encountered the post in the low quality queue and who also recommended its deletion.

That's all normal for the site, as far as I can see the post doesn't answer the question, which is not about installation at all. If the moderator had not stepped in the post could well still have ended up deleted by non-moderators via the low quality queue process.

Comment: Can confirm the post received an NAA flag, as you correctly guessed.

Comment: Can you @RyanM?

Comment: @MahmoudNasr I'm not sure what you mean.